# positive and negative infinity for integral types in c++

Tags: c++, types, infinity, numeric-limits

I am reading about positive and negative infinity in c++.

I read that integral types dont have a infinite value ie. `std::numeric_limits<int>::infinity();` wont work, but `std::numeric_limits<int>::max();` will work and will represent the maximum possible value that can be represented by the integral type.

so the `std::numeric_limits<int>::max();` of the integral type could be taken as its `positive infinite limit` ?

Or the integral type has only the `max value` and the `infinity value` is not true ?

Comment: As far as i know all data types are finite. The max value is a finite value, for example 32bits.

Comment: Can you explain what operations you want to do on integers that involve infinite limits?

Comment: You can associate any meaning to any value. You can even regard '567' as NaN. But there's no (native) support for either proposition in std. The question rather is: what do you want to accomplish?

Comment: actually i am implementing fixedpoint arthimetic and i am trying to define positive and negative infinity for my fixed point types. my fixedpoint is a integral type so when i about the define its positive and negative infinity, i came with this doubt what is the difference between max value and infinity value for a integral type

Comment: You could define a infinity-value in your fixed point math, but it may perhaps be just as good to just let it be `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()` (and it's negative counterpart) - it really depends on what you plan to do, and how you intend to deal with "infinity" - for example is "infinity + infinity = infinity"?

Comment: @MatsPetersson " But it may perhaps be just as good to just let it be `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()` "   so do you mean, just assign the value of the positive infinity of the fixed point equal to `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()` ?

Comment: That's one solution, yes. But it really depends on if "infinity" has a special meaning or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Floating point numbers have a special bit pattern to indicate "the value is infinity", which is used when the result of some operation is defined as infinite.

Integer values have a set number of bits, and all bits are used to represent a numeric value. There is no "special bit pattern", it's just whatever the sum of the bit positions mean.

Edit: On page 315 of my hardcopy of AMD64 Architecture Programmer's Manual, it says

> Infinity. Infinity is a positve or negative number +∞ and
>   -∞, in which the integer bit is 1, the biased exponent is maximum and fraction is 0. The infintes are the maximum numbers that
>   can be represented in floating point format, negative infinity is less
>   than any finite number and positive infinity is greater than any
>   finite number (ie. the affine sense).
>
> And infinite result is produce when a non-zero, non-infinite number is
>   divided by 0 or multiplied by infinity, or when infinity is added to
>   infinity or to 0. Arithmetic infinites is exact. For example, adding
>   any floating point number to +∞ gives a result of +∞
>   Arithmetic comparisons work correctly on infinites. Exceptions occur
>   only when the use of an infinity as a source operand constitutes an
>   invalid operation.

(Any typing mistakes are mine)

Comment: Do you think of `NaN` "Not a Number"? I don't think it's a correct interpretation since `-1/0` as much as `1/0` would return `NaN`.

Comment: No, NaN is different. See my added quote above (too large for a comment). (NaN is a similar encoding, but the fraction is non-zero, and there are actually multiple variants of NaN's).

Comment: Did I miss something from my answer?

Answer (score 3):

Integers are always finite.

The closest you can get to what you're looking for is by setting an integer to it's maximum value, which for a signed integer only around 2 billion something.

std::numeric_limits has a has_infinity member which you can use to check if the type you want has an infinite representation, which are usually only on floating point numbers such as float and double.