# Compile-time optimization for `std::isfinite()` applied to the integral types

Tags: c++, c++17, cmath

I have a design choice to make. I have a templated class `myClass<T>` that has a member `data_` of the type `T`. Currently, the intention is to support `int`, several complex types, and `double`; thus resulting into the templates of three categories: floating-point type, integral type, and complex type.

The function `checkValidity()`, checks the validity of the object of class `myClass` which right now will be limited to simply checking the finiteness of the `data_` by using [`std::isfinite()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isfinite).

Currently, this function is implemented, as follows:

```
template<class T>
bool myClass<T>::checkValidity() const noexcept
{
    if constexpr(std::is_floating_point_v<T> || std::is_integral_v<T>)
    {
        return std::isfinite(this->data_);
    }
    else if constexpr(is_complex<T>{})
    {
        return (std::isfinite(this->data_.real()) && std::isfinite(this->data_.imag()))
    }
    else static_assert(assert_false<T>::value , "wrong type");
}
```

where `is_complex<T>{}` and `assert_false<T>` are simple custom written traits that determine if the type is one of the supported complex ones and simply protect from the compilation with the unsupported type of `T` that has been used for instantiation by mistake, respectively.

Now, I wonder, since [integral types are always finite](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16356163/2452869), does it make sense to move the condition from the first `constexpr if` branch, as follows:

```
if constexpr(std::is_integral_v<T>)
{
    return true;
}
```

?

Since, as far as I understand `std::isfinite(value)`, where `value` is of the integral type would always return `true`.

Pretty much that would boil down to the question:

- does it ever make sense to explicitly check the finiteness of the integral type, when it is known to be integral (as in my example)?
- would I expect a compiler to optimize my unmodified version for the case of `T = int`?

Premises:

- in reality, `data_` is a large array;
- many more things are happening in the `checkValidity()` function;
- this function lies on the critical path of the code;
- the fact that integral types are always finite and [`std::isfinite()` is supposed to check the finiteness by casting to `double`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56357527/2452869) gives me some confidence that I will not get any information from actually performing the check.

Comment: In relation to if the compiler is smart enough to optimise the is_finite call, the answer appears to be yes: https://godbolt.org/z/awCMhc

Comment: You got a typo in your whole question. It is `std::isfinite` not `std::is_finite` ;) Besides that, I agree with @Chuu Plus... `std::isfinite` is not `constexpr`. In case that is important for you...

Comment: @jan.sende thanks a lot! fixed. My attention slipped to make every other syntaxis correct. the fact that `std::isfinite` is not `constexpr` is irrelevant.

Comment: @Chuu good observation!

Answer (score 0):

Over time, you will develop an intuition of what your compiler will optimise into constants.  If you are not sure, and also in order to build your intuition, you should use tools like Compiler Explorer to see what the compiler is actually generating.

[Here](https://godbolt.org/z/7aj_4m) is a very crude mockup of your proposed implementation in Compiler explorer.  If you intuitively expect that `std::isfinite` will evaluate to a constant expression for any integer data types, then the results are not surprising.  Also following that intuition, the `double` case reduces to an inlined `std::isfinite` call, which you can verify in compiler explorer by looking at the generated call for a trivial method that just calls `std::isfinite` for a double.

For actual complex classes, you can use the tool to mock out your Complex class more in depth and see what the compiler does with it.